# Accessing element in array - Request for member in something not a struture or union

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, properties, nsmutablearray

I have created a custom button called `ModuleUIButton` which inherits from `UIButton`. This custom button has an mutable array property called `cycleList`.

I have an mutable array of `ModuleUIButton`'s called `moduleList`. I need to be able to access an element of the `cycleList` mutable array, and I use the following call:

```
//Create ModuleUIButton
ModuleUIButton *newModuleButton = [[ModuleUIButton alloc] 

//Customize ModuleUIButton
initWithFrame:CGRectMake(29.0,  (200.0+(88*moduleCounter)), 692, 80.0)];
[newModuleButton setTitle:@"Module" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[newModuleButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];

//Add newModuleButton to moduleList array
[moduleList addObject:newModuleButton];

//Access the first element in moduleList which is newModuleButton and add
// a string to it's cycleList property
[[self.moduleList objectAtIndex:0].cycleList addObject:@"new Cycle"];
```

When attempting to compile however, I get:

> Request for member 'cycleList' in something not a structure or a Union

Is the compiler complaining because it doesnt know that `moduleList`'s 0th element will be a `ModuleUIButton`? If so, how can I access any of the `ModuleUIButton`s properties by referencing it from the mutable array?

Any insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the compiler complaining because it doesnt know that `moduleList`'s 0th element will be a `ModuleUIButton`?

Exactly. The return type of `objectAtIndex:` is `id`. The compiler can't know what the *actual* type is, and can't therefore turn the property access `.cycleList` into the correct method call as it normally would, because it can't know what the correct method is.

The property access essentially works by *rewriting* your code. The complier sees `foo.bar` and goes to `foo`'s class, finds the methods that correspond to the `bar` property, and turns what you wrote into `[foo bar]` or `[foo setBar:]`, as appropriate. The trick is that, since the methods associated with a property can have any name (not just the standard `bar`/`setBar`) the compiler *must* be able to determine the type of the object in order to figure out the right method names to use.

When you use the bracket syntax, you're telling the compiler the exact name of the method you want called. It doesn't have to do any lookup, it just turns that into the usual call to `objc_msgSend`.

> If so, how can I access any of the `ModuleUIButton`'s properties by referencing it from the mutable array?

Just use the "standard" syntax:

```
[[self.moduleList objectAtIndex:0] cycleList]
```

You can also give the compiler a hint by casting, as Taskinoor suggested:

```
((ModuleUIButton *)[self.moduleList objectAtIndex:0]).cycleList
```

This explicitly tells the compiler to treat the object being returned from `objectAtIndex:` as a `ModuleUIButton`; it can then figure out what the method name should be.

Comment: Casting seemed to do it! I should've realized that it was returning an id XD Thanks for the detailed explanation!

Comment: PS: Why does the compiler treat the "normal syntax" `[[[self.moduleList objectAtIndex:0] cycleList] addObject:@"new Cycle"]` any differently than the syntax I was using `[self.moduleList objectAtIndex:0].cycleList addObject:@"new Cycle"]`? Arent they the exact same thing?

Comment: Good question! I've added the explanation to my answer.

Comment: ahh, so by calling `[foo bar]` rather than `foo.bar`, we are essentially doing some of the identification work for the compiler?

Comment: Sort of. The compiler doesn't have to do any identification at all with the bracket syntax. The method is resolved at runtime.

Comment: hmmmm, sorry to bring you back to this issue, but when I attempt to retrieve the value that I placed, I'm returning `null`. My call is `NSLog(@"%@",[[[self.moduleList objectAtIndex:0] cycleList] objectAtIndex:0])`

Comment: This will turn into a separate question very quickly, so if you can't solve it, I'd say post a new one, but either the `cycleList` isn't getting set up properly, or (if this `NSLog` call isn't adjacent to the code you posted above) `moduleList` is being set to `nil` when you don't expect, or not set up in the first place.

Comment: Figured it out :) The `cycleList` indeed wasn't being initialized correctly...let alone at all. I had assumed that since it was a property, of `ModuleUIButton`, it was initialized upon the creation of `ModuleUIButton` :P Phail on my part.

Answer (score 1):

Try to cast like this:

```
ModuleUIButton *button = (ModuleUIButton *)[self.moduleList objectAtIndex:0];
[button.cycleList addObject:@"new Cycle"];
```